# Default values in complex REST request object

Tags: java, spring, rest

When we use *@RequestParam* annotation on **REST** request method, we are able to specify, if that value is required, and it's default value. But how to achieve that when we let Spring map request parameters to some complex object? Is it possible to annotate that object's fields as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the complex object ,you can use @ModelAttribute annotation.Or you can use annnotation given by bean validation API also.For ex @Valid(JSR annotation),and then you can add the necessary validation like for empty,range check or default in the fields of your complex object.

Comment: I think using BeanValidation will be the best option here. Thanks.

Comment: Joining this question a bit late, but I'm just wondering: how would you be able to default the fields of your complex object other than by initializing the attributes with that specific value? In that case, if an attribute in the url would be attr=null, that null will override whatever I've set there.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for

```
9 @Controller 

10 public class ModelAttributeExampleController {  

11     @Autowired 

12     private UserDetails userDetails;  

13     @RequestMapping(value="/modelexample")  

14     public String getMethod(@ModelAttribute UserDetails userDetails){  

15         System.out.println("User Name : " + userDetails.getUserName());  

16         System.out.println("Email Id : " + userDetails.getEmailId());  

17         return "example";  

18     }  

19    

20     //This method is invoked before the above method  

21     @ModelAttribute 

22     public UserDetails getAccount(@RequestParam String user, @RequestParam String emailId){  

23         System.out.println("User Value from Request Parameter : " + user);  

24         userDetails.setUserName(user);  

25         userDetails.setEmailId(emailId);  

26         return userDetails;  

27     }  

28 }
```

Source : http://www.javabeat.net/modelattribute-spring-mvc/

Comment: Not really, because i still need to specify ModelAttribute method's parameters.